# Atmega 16 - Timer0 with interrupt

Tags: microcontroller, led, avr, atmega, avr-gcc

In this code the one LED is glowing at one pin PC0 with flash every 50 ms. It has XTAL of 16 MHz. With CPU frequency 16 MHz, even a maximum delay of 16.384 ms can be achieved using a 1024 prescaler. Every 256 prescalar value, it is achieving interrupt.

1. DDRC |= (1 << 0).... In the given code, what does it mean.
2. I want to glow all LED at PORTC. For this, what i have to change in
   DDRC |= (1 << 0).

---

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile uint8_t tot_overflow;

void timer0_init()
{
    TCCR0 |= (1 << CS02);
    TCNT0 = 0;
    TIMSK |= (1 << TOIE0);
    sei();
    tot_overflow = 0;
}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    tot_overflow++;
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRC |= (1 << 0);
     timer0_init();
    while(1)
    {
        if (tot_overflow >= 12)  
        {
            if (TCNT0 >= 53)
            {
                PORTC ^= (1 << 0);    
                TCNT0 = 0;            
                tot_overflow = 0;     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you... had a chance to look at the datasheet yet?

Comment: No Sir, i didn't.. is it given in datasheet?

Answer (score 1):

1. **DDRC |= (1 << 0)** - It means that you're setting pin PC0 as output
2. You need to set PC0-PC7 pins as outputs to make all LEDS glow by doing something like this **DDRC  = 0b11111111**

[Read Bitwise operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)!

[Read a datasheet!](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2466.pdf)

Comment: But sir, i have changed this. DDRC=0b11111111 is not giving any output.

Comment: Try with DDRC = 0xFF.

Comment: DDRC=0xFF and DDRC=0b11111111 is same.

Comment: You solved your problem?

Comment: Yes sir, i have solved.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`DDRC|=(1<<0)` sets PC0 as output. `DDRC=0b11111111` (or OxFF, or 255), sets PC0-7 as output.

Then you *also* need to set the pin high. That's what `PORTC ^= (1 << 0)` does (actually `^` is a bitwise xor, so it toggles the pin from high to low and vice versa). If you want to toggle all pins simultaneously, `PORTC ^= (0b11111111)` will do.